# Is there something like an "originalScope" property in the jquery event-object?

Tags: jquery, events, scope, event-listener

Something like a "originalScrop" property in the event Object would be very usefull.
Or is there a other solution?

```
{
    show: function(){
        $(document).on('keydown',this.keydownListener);
    },
    keydownListener: function(e){
        if(e.which===27){ o.originalScope.hide(); } // <----- originalScope
    },
    hide: function(){
        $(document).off('keydown',this.keydownListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `this` to point to your object in your event handlers, use [**$.proxy**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) when setting them:

```
$(document).on('keydown', $.proxy(this.keydownListener, this));
```

... which does essentially the same work as [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind): for the given function and object creates another function that has its `this` value bound to the specific object.

Comment: Is it possible to later remove the eventLitener?
$(document).off('keydown',this.keydownListener);

Comment: If `this` refers to that object where it's defined, of course.